# How does the proposed Microsoft .NET Gageteer compare to other systems?

Tags: .net-micro-framework

I'm a .NET developer interested in the [.NET Gadgeteer](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/gadgeteer/default.aspx).  Based on what's public, how does it compare to other devices?

If you're interested, [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Clint/NET-Gadgeteer) is a Channel9 video that shows you how to use VS2010 to create an embedded application. It is due to release in Spring of 2011...

Comment: I predict pathological fear of "M$" will prevent widespread adoption, even though people are frequently just as "locked in" when they choose particular MCUs.

Comment: Normally it is harder to change MCUs then it is to change OS or development platform for the MCU.

Comment: I wonder why there is a negative vote on this question (with no comment)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the [Netduino platform](http://netduino.com/) . It also uses .NET Micro framework, so you can develop and debug in standard Visual Studio. And it is largely hardware compatible with Arduino accessories, so there are a lot of hardware modules out there that you can connect to it without having to design them from scratch. Not all Arduino shields are compatible, so you may want to check out the list on the forums on the Netduino site.
Low-cost as well ($35 from SparkFun and some other vendors).

The Netduino Plus has just been released, and it adds onboard Ethernet and microSD, with libraries to drive them. There is also a Netduino Mini, on a small DIP carrier.

Anyway, if you want something small and cheap that you can use to control hardware and still be able to develop in .NET, take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it tries to do the same as a normal Embedded linux with Qt platform can do today. 
Feel free to compare with the MeeGo project and let's say a Beagleboard.

But my guess is that you will be locked in on this .net platform.

But I get the feeling that they have created a more flashy version of the Lego Mindstorms system, but without the lego parts and with a little cooler hardware....